# how to trigger an action by clicking a link in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am coming rails framework experience. I have a simple problem.

I have a link on a page.  I want some Struts2 action executed when the user clicks the link and want to pass along some parameters.

For example:

```
link on page = My Link
Action I want to call = myTestAction (it is defined in struts.xml)
parameter I want to pass = typeA=false
```

How can I do this?  I looked at `<s:url><s:param name="typeA" value="false"></s:url>` tag.  However, the parameter doesnt seem to get pass. when I hover on the link i do not see any parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Try This..

```
<s:url id="url" action="myTestAction">
    <s:param name="typeA">false</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{url}" >My Link</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the action class needs to have `setTypeA(String value)` `and getTypeA()` declared in it for the above code to pass `typeA=false`

I dont know why they would do this...or maybe rails has spoiled me.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <s:url action="actionNameInStrutsXML" method="methodNameInYourClass" var="menuAdmin" />
          <s:a href="%{menuAdmin}">Menu</s:a>
```

In this way you can call the method that you prefer.

Remember to put in your struts config this:

> struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"

Answer (score 0):

I think @vinayak answer is perfect if you want to send more than one parameter use `escapeAmp=false`